# The localhost address in front of the django image url

Tags: python, django

[image]

[image]

When i get an image, some models put "http://localhost:8000" at the beginning and some models don't. I want to unify it in one way, but how can I express it without attaching "http://localhost:8000"?

Comment: Are you using Django Rest Framework? If the serializer is passed the request in its context it uses that to make the absolute url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the build_absolute_uri. I do it the following way:

```
object_serialized = ModelSerializer(object)
        object_data = object_serialized.data.copy()
        if object_data['goal_image']:
            object_data['goal_image'] = request.build_absolute_uri(
                object.goal_image.url)

        return Response(object_data)
```

If you share your code, we may be able to provide more accurate advise.